# Passing context object name to html directly like href="{% url 'profileEdit' here %}" in django

Tags: django

Here I am trying to edit the profile of the user which is currently logged in.

urls.py

```
path('profileEdit/<int:pk>/',views.profileEdit.as_view(),name='profileEdit'),
```

views.py

```
class profileEdit(UpdateView):
    model =  Profile
    fields = ['bio', 'photo']
    template_name = 'Blog/profileEdit.html'
    success_url = '/newsfeed/'
    context_object_name = 'form'
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

def profileuser():
    me = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    contex={
     'u':me.pk,
    }

    return render(request,'Blog/base.html',contex)
```

base.html

```
<div class="dropdown-menu">
     <a class="dropdown-item" style="font-size:20px;color:red" href="{% url 'profileEdit' something %}">Edit Profile
     </a>
```

I want to put something in `something` through which can get URL like 'profileEdit/2/'. In place of something we can put like `request.user.pk` but the problem is that I don't want to get user pk. Instead of that, I want profile pk so, I created `profileuser` function through which I can pass context object to html url but don't know how to do.

Answer (score 0):

add this in your update function

```
lookup_field = 'pk'
```

and in place of something add 'u' . this u is that you are passing in context dictionary in your `profileuser() function`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. If is pass directly 'u' in place of something then i will get Exception Type:NoReverseMatch error because it is expecting  a number not queryset.